# How to use Pivot without using aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I am using MS Sql2008,

```
     Table1: Plan.Plan
     Table2: Plan.PlanFeature
     Table3:Plan.PlanDetails

    Plan.Plan

    PlanID_PK    PlanName  AnnualPrice  MonthlyPrice

  1                   Plan1            Free              Free
  2                   Plan2            $50.00          $4.99
  3                   Plan3            $100.00        $9.99

Plan.PlanFeature

PlanFeatureID_PK    FeatureName
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        1                           Feature1
        2                           Feature2
        3                           Feature3
        4                           Feature4


Plan.PlanDetails

PlanDetailsID_PK    PlanID_FK    PlanFeatureID_FK    Quantity     Quantity_Type
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - -
             1                        1                   1                                0               Included
             2                        1                   2                                0               Unlimited
             3                        1                   3                                2               None
             4                        1                   4                                0               Unlimited
             5                        2                   1                                0               Included
             6                        2                   2                                0               Unlimited
             7                        2                   3                                20               None
             8                        2                   4                                0               Unlimited
             9                        3                   1                                0               Included
             10                      3                   2                                0               Unlimited
             11                      3                   3                                >20               None
             12                      3                   4                                0               Unlimited




Output :

FeatureName     Plan1          Plan2         Plan3  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Feature1          Included      Included      Included
Feature2          Unlimited     Unlimited    Unlimited
Feature3              2                    20                >20
Feature4          Unlimited     Unlimited     Unlimited
AnnualPrice     Free             $50.00           $100.00
MonthlyPrice   Free             $4.99              $9.99
```

So here we go,  For converting rows into columns I used COALESCE and Pivot

Here the stored procedure I am trying it,

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SubjectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + PlanNames + ']',
                         '[' + PlanNames + ']')
FROM    Plans.Plans
ORDER BY PlanNames
SET @SubjectQuery = 'SELECT FeatureName, ' + @cols + '
FROM 
(select p.PlanId_PK, p.PlanNames,pf.FeatureName,pd.Quantity from Plans.PlanDetails pd 
join Plans.Plans p on pd.PlanId_FK=p.PlanId_PK 
join Plans.PlanFeatures pf on pd.PlanFeatureId_FK=pf.PlanFeatureId_PK  ) S
PIVOT
(
Count(Quantity) --Dont know which aggregate functions i have to use here according to my output
FOR PlanNames IN
(' + @cols + ')) AS pvt'
exec @SubjectQuery
```

For quantity I have to check condition like this `MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Quantity = '0' THEN pd.Quantity_Type)as Quantity`, if the quantity value is 0 then i have to display `Quantity_type` values

Inside the pivot block don't know which aggregate function i have to use according to my output, can you please figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample data and the desire output, I think you will want to use the `case` inside of the subquery, before the `pivot`:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SubjectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + PlanName + ']',
                         '[' + PlanName + ']')
FROM    [Plans]
ORDER BY PlanName


SET @SubjectQuery 
   = 'SELECT FeatureName, ' + @cols + '
      FROM 
      (
        select p.PlanName,
          pf.FeatureName,
              MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Quantity = ''0'' THEN pd.Quantity_Type else quantity end)as Quantity
        from PlanDetails pd 
        join [Plans] p 
          on pd.PlanId_FK=p.PlanId_PK 
        join PlanFeature pf 
          on pd.PlanFeatureId_FK=pf.PlanFeatureId_PK  
        group by p.PlanName, pf.FeatureName
      ) S
      PIVOT
      (
        max(Quantity)
        FOR PlanName IN (' + @cols + ')
      ) AS pvt'

exec(@SubjectQuery);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3438/34).

The result is:

```
| FEATURENAME |     PLAN1 |     PLAN2 |     PLAN3 |
---------------------------------------------------
|    Feature1 |  Included |  Included |  Included |
|    Feature2 | Unlimited | Unlimited | Unlimited |
|    Feature3 |         2 |        20 |       >20 |
|    Feature4 | Unlimited | Unlimited | Unlimited |
```

Edit, If you need the annual price and monthly price, then you will need to incorporate an `unpivot` and the `pivot` function:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SubjectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + PlanName + ']',
                         '[' + PlanName + ']')
FROM    [Plans]
ORDER BY PlanName


SET @SubjectQuery 
   = 'SELECT FeatureName,'+@cols+'
      FROM 
      (
          select PlanName, FeatureName, 
              MAX(CASE WHEN Quantity = ''0'' THEN Quantity_Type else quantity end)as Quantity,
              SortOrder
          from
          (
              select p.PlanName, pf.FeatureName, pd.Quantity, pd.Quantity_Type, 1 Sortorder
              from PlanDetails pd 
              join [Plans] p 
                on pd.PlanId_FK=p.PlanId_PK 
              join PlanFeature pf 
                on pd.PlanFeatureId_FK=pf.PlanFeatureId_PK  
              union all
              select PlanName, col, ''0'', value, 2 SortOrder
              from
              (
                  select PlanID_PK, PlanName,
                      AnnualPrice, 
                      cast(MonthlyPrice as varchar(6)) MonthlyPrice
                  from plans
              ) src
              unpivot
              (
                  value
                  for col in (annualprice, monthlyprice)
              ) unpiv
          ) pl
          group by PlanName, FeatureName, SortOrder
      ) d
      PIVOT
      (
          max(Quantity)
          FOR PlanName IN ('+@cols+')
      ) AS pvt
      order by SortOrder'

exec(@SubjectQuery);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3438/43)

Result:

```
|  FEATURENAME |     PLAN1 |     PLAN2 |     PLAN3 |
----------------------------------------------------
|     Feature1 |  Included |  Included |  Included |
|     Feature2 | Unlimited | Unlimited | Unlimited |
|     Feature3 |         2 |        20 |       >20 |
|     Feature4 | Unlimited | Unlimited | Unlimited |
|  AnnualPrice |      Free |     50.00 |    100.00 |
| MonthlyPrice |      Free |      4.99 |      9.99 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For quantity I have to check condition like MAX(CASE WHEN Quantity = '0' THEN Quantity_Type end),if the quantity value is 0 then i have to display Quantity_type values, If i apply this condition inside the pivot i am getting error like 'Incorrect syntax near case'

Comment: @JavaH did you see my updated answer?  and the demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3438/34

Comment: did you see my output which have mentioned above in that two more rows need to be added ie.annual price and monthly price.So do we need to use another Pivot to get the actual output.?

Comment: In  plan.plan table Annual price and monthly price is specified as column so do we need to do the reverse process like making column to rows using pivot before i done  making rows to column using pivot...can you please help to figure this out?

Comment: @JavaH see my edit. You will want to use an `unpivot` and a `union all` to add the annual price and monthly price